# how to convert bytes into kb in java

Tags: java, spring, file-io

Here I am getting file size in bytes format in

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile.getSize();
```

but I want to convert this to kb format, how can I convert bytes into kb's in java.

Comment: divide it by 1024

Comment: I'm assuming you want to convert to kilobyte and not kilobit. Have a look at [the Wikipedia article on kilobyte](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte) is has links to other units, for example the multiples of 10

Answer (score 2):

1 Kilobyte = 1000 bytes
1 Kibibyte = 1024 bytes

long bytes = org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile.getSize();
long kilobytes = bytes / 1000;
long kibibytes = bytes / 1024;

[Kilobyte in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte)

Answer (score 0):

In Java, and any other language, divide by 1024 to get kb.